# $.each inside $.append (Object [object Array] has no method 'apply')

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, each

I am trying to `$.append` dynamically constructed elements inside a dynamically constructed element inside of a custom plugin:

```
$('<div/>').append( function(){
    $.each(paramaterObject.rows, function(rowKey, rowValue){
        return $('<div/>')...
```

but Chrome console gives `Object [object Array] has no method 'apply'`.

Is it possible to `$.append()` this way?  If not, is there an alternative?  Please show me how.

Comment: just learned a lot from my last 3 questions, but one might want to look here if going down the same road as i was: http://json2html.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
    var parentDiv = $('<div/>');
    $.each(paramaterObject.rows, function(rowKey, rowValue){
        parentDiv.append($('<div/>'));
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't return from the iterator -- you have to keep a buffer that you fill, and return the buffer when all iterations are done.

Something in the lines of;

```
$('<div />').append(function () {

    var buffer = "";
    $.each (parameterObject.rows, function () {
        buffer += "<div />";
    });
    return buffer;

});
```

Comment: "No, you can't return from the iterator.." i would say returns in iterators are used to tell `.each()` to stop itering. +1 anyway.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, it actually doesn't stop the iterator -- it works as `continue` does in a regular for-loop (just skips the current iteration).

Comment: Sorry if I missexplained myself. What i meant is that you can use return in each, but it is used to stop the loop (with `return false`).